# Javascript Confirm in HTML Form not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which creates a number of `Form`s dynamically that have `Input` buttons that link to a file delObservation.php that then deletes the record. I want to have a `Confirm` function included and have added this script. The `Confirm` message box appears but even if I click 'Cancel' on the confirm message box the delObservation.php  still gets called. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkDelete(){
return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');
}
</script>

<form name="deleteReport" action="http://www.website/delRecord.php" method="Post">
    <input name="recordID" type="submit" 
           value="<?php echo$row['recordID'] ?>" class="delButton" 
           onclick="checkDelete()" >
</form>
```

Comment: You should use `onsubmit` attribute on `<form>` element, instead of `onclick` on button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `input onclick` event:

```
//from 
onclick="checkDelete()"
//to
onclick="return checkDelete()"
```

It will cancel the default action if return value is false.

For example:

```
//to do the default action regardless return value of the function
onclick="checkDelete();" //Or
onclick="checkDelete(); return true;"

//to cancel the default action regardless return value of the function
onclick="checkDelete(); return false;"

//to decide the action depending return value of the function
//Your requirement
onclick="return checkDelete();"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
<input name="recordID" type="submit" value="<?php echo$row['recordID'] ?>" 
class="delButton" onSubmit="return checkDelete()">
                  ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `return` to the `onclick` like below:

```
<input name="recordID" type="submit" value="<?php echo $row['recordID'] ?>" class="delButton" onclick="return checkDelete()">
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WNYya/1/)

Also, I noticed there is no space after php `echo`